# How to bind port to localhost?

Tags: linux, hdfs, port, ip-address, iptables

I have an hadoop defaultFs application run in port 8020, as show with  `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8020`, where `10.44.142.19` is the internal address,

```
tcp        0      0 10.44.142.19:8020           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      31680/java
```

I also opened this port in iptables

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8020
```

But this port is still blocked.

I guess is the problem of ip address, where `10.44.142.19` should be `127.0.0.1`, because I am visiting it from external, right?

How could I solve this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

ok if you are coming in from the WAN you need to use your ip from your modem. google "whats my ip" If you are behind a router, your router will give you an ip of something like, 192.168.10.101 type that in goto your sever over a LAN.

:8020 at the end if that is your port you are directing to.

firewall must be down for that port to come from the outside, and your web server must be setup to make the files and folders you want to disturb or make available with permission of at least read for your web servers user or group, in permissions.

each system is a little different so you have to tweek things as you go.